# How to run a .cmd file from within PHP and display the results

Tags: php, batch-file, cmd, windows-server-2003

I need to run a .cmd batch file from within a php script.

The PHP will be accessed via an authenticated session within a browser.

When I run the .cmd file from the desktop of the server, it spits out some output to cmd.exe.

I'd like to route this output back to the php page.

Is this doable?

Comment: [added comment again because the link was borked] Won't enclosing the .cmd file in backticks do it, like the example with the .bat file here? http://www.php.net/manual/pl/language.operators.execution.php

Comment: Something like this? I don't have PHP handy right now so can't test this, sorry!

<?php 
$par= "my_parameter"; 
$test=\`c:\mybat.bat $par\`; 
echo "<pre>$test</pre>"; 
?>

Comment: @hamlin11 - What doesn't work about it("print `ls`;")? I just tested it(on a linux machine, though) and it worked fine for me. Try:

Comment: just curious, what does the cmd file do?

Comment: runs 7zip and does a few file management things

Comment: Related, [How do you run a .bat file from PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/835941)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is doable. You can use

```
exec("mycommand.cmd", &$outputArray);
```

and print the content of the array:

```
echo implode("\n", $outputArray);
```

[look here for more info](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = `whatever.cmd`;
print $result; // Prints the result of running "whatever.cmd"
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use [popen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php) for this kind of task. Especially for long-running commands, because you can fetch output line-by-line and send it to browser, so there is less chance of timeout. Here's an example:

```
$p = popen('script.cmd', 'r');
if ($p)
{
    while (!feof($p))
        echo gets($p);    // get output line-by-line
    pclose($p);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`shell_exec`](http://php.net/shell_exec), or the [backticks operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php), to launch a command and get the output as a string.

If you want to pass parameters to that command, you should envisage using [escapeshellargs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) to escape them before calling the command ; and you might take a look at [escapeshellcmd](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php) too ^^

Answer (score 1):

Use the php popen() function