# PHP + Command Line Execution

Tags: php, command-line, exec

I'm trying to run a .bat file using PHP from the command-line. I'm using Windows Vista Home Premium.

When I use the script on a file like ipconfig.exe, I get the output. However, when I run the .bat file, it gives me output of what is in the file but it doesn't execute it.

What is below works and give me output:

```
$runCommand = "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\ipconfig.exe";
$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$output = $WshShell->Exec($runCommand)->StdOut->ReadAll;
echo "<p>$output</p>";
```

But this doesn't:

```
$runCommand = "C:\\Temp\\foo.bat";
$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$output = $WshShell->Exec($runCommand)->StdOut->ReadAll;
echo "<p>$output</p>";
```

Here's what's in my foo.bat file:

```
C:/windows/system32/schtasks.exe /create /tn "TestTask" /tr "C:/Temp/configure.php" /sc minute /st 08:00:00
```

If I copy this and paste in my Windows Command Line, this command executes successfully.

Not sure what is going on. Kindly assist.

Comment: 12 questions, 1 accepted answer. Please read the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 1):

That's because a bat file is a queued list of commands for a prompt. Try the following:

`cmd /c myfile.bat`

(it may be /k too, forget which executes and closes)

Also, duplicate of [How do you run a .bat file from PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835941/how-do-you-run-a-bat-file-from-php)

**EDIT**

```
<?php
  // http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#85930

  $_ = null;

  // If you care about the return value, use this:
    passthru("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe /c custom.bat",$_);
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    echo $_;
  // if you don't care, just use this:
    $_ = exec("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe /c custom.bat");
?>
```

Comment: I replaced C:\\Temp\\foo.bat with C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe /k C:\\Temp\\foo.bat but it still doesn't execute.

Comment: Please see the link I mentioned in my answer that points tot he other question relating to batch files and php. They have a wonderful example in the accepted answer.

Comment: I tried exec('C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c START C:\Temp\foo.bat', $out), but it crashed my Apache server. Not sure how you got that to work?!

Comment: Please see my updated answer. Also, be sure to mark it as accepted since I've googling and RTM'n for you.

Comment: Tried this: $_ = null; passthru("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe /c C:\\Temp\\foo.bat",$_); header('Content-Type: text/plain'); echo $_; Still not working.

Comment: Also tried: $_ = exec("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe /c C:\\Temp\\cronwin.bat"); Doesn't work either. I wonder if there was a way to tweak my initial script, at least with that I did get some output, but maybe I missed something in the declaration.

Comment: Then you're probably running in safe mode or something is off on your configuration. what does `echo php_get('save_mode');` return? Could also be listed in `echo ini_get('disable_functions');`

Comment: php_get gives me a 'Call to undefined function error', ini_get('disable_functions') gives me nothing.

Comment: Sorry, ini_get in both scenarios.

Comment: No output to the screen with ini_get('save_mode')

Comment: Can definitely tell it's getting late in the say, `ini_get('safe_mode');` On both accounts, my mistake. If that doesn't work I'm out of solutions. Something is messed up and I'm not sure what. All I can recommend is try going to your php directory and finding `php.ini-recommended`, copy it, and rename the copy to php.ini (all in same folder) then try again. If that doesn't work, exhaust google.

Comment: I figured, I should have noticed that myself. My php.ini file has safe_mode set as Off. Not sure what might be causing this. Could it be my Windows version?!

Comment: Unless it has something to do with the UAC disabling PHP from running the script (possible). But your web service should be running at elevated privileges (and I assume the execution is spawned off the service, thus inheriting the same authorities). Do a search against PHP Windows 7 and exec/passthhru.

Comment: Ok. I get output when I do something simple like this: exec('C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\ipconfig.exe', $out); print_r($out); So I figure exec() is working. It just seems like I'm missing something in the syntax. Anyway, thanks, I'll keep looking for a solution.