# Can't get .bat to run with PHP on WAMP localhost

Tags: php, batch-file, exec

I've been busting my head against the wall on this one for hours and I can't make any progress.

Right now I've simmered down my problem to the simple (maybe?) task of trying to get a PHP script to run a .bat program, on localhost. I'm using WAMP.

This is my current PHP file:

`<?php system('cmd /c C:\Users\user\Desktop\open.bat'); ?>`

That's all there is in it. My .bat file, which is on the desktop, contains:

`notepad.exe C:\Users\user\Desktop\test.txt`

And then I have a simple text file called test.txt on the desktop. I can run the .bat file from the command line and it works fine, but nothing from within the PHP.

There's numerous other threads here asking how to run a .bat from PHP (ex: [How do you run a .bat file from PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835941/how-do-you-run-a-bat-file-from-php)), and I've tried pretty much every technique I've read about online, and NOTHING WORKS.

Ex, I've tried

`exec('open.bat')` (with the .bat in the same directory), `shell_exec()`, changing around the locations of files, paths, I really don't know what's up with it. I'm not running PHP in safe mode.

Perhaps there's some configuration that I should know about that will allow it to run? Or maybe I'm missing something painfully obvious...

Comment: Any errors while execution? Or just blank result?

Comment: Just blank result; no errors in the console or anywhere else I can see.

Comment: *note* I tried putting the .bat in the same directory as the PHP file, and changing its contents to `exec('open.bat');` - it now is stuck 'waiting for localhost' if that changes anything...

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that you don't see Notepad run because it's an interactive program and the web server (which is trying to start it) runs in a different user session than the one *you* are in. Doing the same from the command line (e.g. with `php -f`) would work in that case.

Comment: in which case shellrunas might help you: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc300361.aspx

Comment: I just discovered a setting in Apache to 'allow Apache to communicate with the desktop' - after setting that and restarting WAMP, the .bat at least runs!

Comment: so I think it's running under the correct user.. However, it now opens up 'interactive services detection' (a Windows utility), which tells me that 'a program running on this computer is trying to display a message', which may have happened because 'the program may not be compatible with Windows'. When I click 'view the message', it exits Windows Explorer and takes me to a blank blue screen with the Notepad file on it - so it opens! But in a really weird way. I really am not quite sure what's going on with it..

Comment: @Nik: The user that Apache runs as has a separate desktop, which is what you see. I 'm not sure about the fine print here, but did you look at that shellrunas link?

Comment: Ok I'm trying it with shellrunas - the interactive services detection still opens, only now shellrunas is running in it rather than the .bat

Comment: It seems like there's some setting within Windows or Apache that won't allow me to run anything from within my PHP files..

Answer (score 0):

you could try using `start /b C:\Users\user\Desktop\open.bat` instead of `cmd`

also you might have to escape the slashes, like so `\\` instead of `\`

So, I suggest you try:

`<?php system('start /b C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\open.bat'); ?>`

Comment: But the single quotes would not allow escape characters right?

Answer (score 0):

Try This....

```
<?php
$cmd = C:\Users\user\Desktop\open.bat;
function execInBackground($cmd) {
   if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){
       pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r")); 
   }
   else {
       exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");  
   }
}
execInBackground($cmd);
?>
```

For more refer: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php