# Running command prompt from a php script using xampp

Tags: php, xampp

I am trying to run the command prompt using a php script on camps but I am unable to do it.

I could run the Explorer using

```
exec("explorer");
```

But when I try to run

```
exec("C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe");
```

It doesn't execute 
How do it do it?

I want to run a command like

```
ping Google.com
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26908929/how-to-open-a-new-cmd-window-using-php

Comment: Yeah it's a duplicate but that thread doesn't have the solution working

Answer (score 0):

This reads commands from the standard input and executes them:

```
while (true) {
    $command = readline("Command: ");
    passthru($command);
}
```

Note that if you run a command like `ping`, you might not be able to stop it this way (usually you would hit <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd>). However you can specify the number of pings to send:

```
ping -c 3 google.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "exec()" function to run the code in background. The command prompt won't be displayed but will directly run the code.

Now if you had to run a python script from php:

You could use

```
exec("py "location of python script");
exec('py C:\xampp\htdocs\pro\helloworld.py');
```

The output would be in the directory where your php script is present.