# Executing Scripts via PHP

Tags: php, batch-file, autohotkey

I am trying to execute a script file (Batch or Python) in PHP (local WAMP server) that will open a program on my computer and send a keyboard shortcut to put the the program in fullscreen mode. I have this script already made using AutoHotKey (.ahk scripts).

I tried using these PHP commands to open a Batch file that runs the .ahk script:

```
system("cmd /c C:\wamp64\www\test.bat");
exec("test.bat");
exec("cmd.exe /c test.bat");
```

But all of these seem to just run the script on the webserver and not on my Windows computer so the .ahk file is never executed. I also tried directly executing .ahk file but I couldn't get that working either.

Does anyone know of a way I can use PHP(or another web language) to execute this script on my computer?

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, I tried changing the log on settings for "wampapache64" to my personal account and I also tried allowing desktop interactions however neither worked (after service restart).

Comment: Related, [How do you run a .bat file from PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/835941)

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify absolute path for the batch file, as the CLI SAPI has nothing to do with WAMP's document root.

You have tried to pass full path in the first command. But the sequence `\t` within double quotes is parsed as a tabulation character. Change double quotes to single quotes:

```
system('cmd /c C:\wamp64\www\test.bat');
```

Also, I don't think you need to run `cmd` explicitly, since batch files are executable on Windows.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out but that is still did not fix the problem. I also followed Aniket's advice of changing the log on settings but I am still unable to execute anything on the user side of my computer.

Comment: @pclever1, why do you think the file is not executed?

Comment: I agree that it is a permissions issue, I changed the Apache log on settings in the windows services manager like the tutorial above described but that still is not executing batch files using  this command `system('cmd /c C:\wamp64\www\test.bat');`