# PHP exec() fails when trying to run .bat file

Tags: python, php, batch-file, exec

I have a server running from XAMPP on my pc and when I try to run `exec('generate_image.bat')` it returns false, so it fails. However when I run the .bat myself it runs perfectly. The exec method also runs perfectly when I run a second, 'test.bat' file, located in the same directory. The script is supposed to start a python program, that generates an image with Stable Diffusion.

Here are my PHP and .bat codes:

PHP:

```php
<?php
    $command = 'generate_image.bat';
    if(!exec($command, $output)) {
        echo "Exec failed";
    } else {
        echo "Exec finished\n<br>\n";
        echo implode("\n", $output);
    }
?>
```

generate_image.bat

```bash
@echo off
g:
cd "G:\User\VS Code\Python\Stable Diffusion"
python main.py
```

test.bat

```bash
@echo off
echo Test
echo Test2
```

I cannot figure out what's going on.

Tried running the file both with `system()` and with `exec()`, using both relative and full paths, and outside of code (this one worked).

Comment: Did you check this out  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835941/how-do-you-run-a-bat-file-from-php

Comment: What is the `.bat` for? Can't you run your `python.exe main.py` directly via `exec()`?

Comment: Unfortunately not, since I noticed that messes with relative paths (it wouldn't find temp.png for example, which was in the directory of the python code).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you run a .bat file from PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835941/how-do-you-run-a-bat-file-from-php)

Comment: No, I tried all of the answers from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem after looking at the Apache's error.log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\User\VS Code\Python\Stable Diffusion\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

My modules were only installed to my user, I fixed this by uninstalling them, then opening cmd in administrator mode and running `pip install`.

Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

When you run `exec` in PHP, you should not rely on the environment variables (including path) to execute the command(s). Hence, you should provide full-paths.

So, assuming that the python.exe is in location `c:\python3.9\python.exe`, then please change generate_image.bat from

```
@echo off
g:
cd "G:\User\VS Code\Python\Stable Diffusion"
python main.py
```

to

```
@echo off
c:\python3.9\python.exe "G:\User\VS Code\Python\Stable Diffusion\main.py"
```

Comment: If there is a need to change the working directory, which you haven't catered for in your answer above, use ```@PushD "G:\User\VS Code\Python\Stable Diffusion" 2>NUL || Exit /B``` as the first line instead, then use ```@"C:\python3.9\python.exe" "main.py"``` as the second line. Or do it in a single line, ```@PushD "G:\User\VS Code\Python\Stable Diffusion" 2>NUL && "C:\python3.9\python.exe" "main.py"```.

Comment: I tried this, however sadly the problem still remains :/